# iOS Swift Update To Web-service When Network Connection Is Available

Tags: ios, realm

In our iOS mobile app we have forms to create, edit and delete certain resources.

We want a user of our app to be able to create and delete these resources when offline and have them update to the webservice when a connection is available.

On Android we use a library by Evernote based on JobQueues which allows us to schedule a job to run when the network is available.

[Evernote Android-Job Github](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)

Is there an equivalent technology available in iOS or what is the recommended approach to achieving the same queue effect.

On iOS we use Realm as our on-device database and Alamofire as a network library.

Comment: Use Firebase instead ;) https://firebase.google.com

Comment: You'll probably need to write the job queue yourself (this *is* iOS after all), but you can see https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift for detecting if network is available

Answer (score 0):

Realm Sync can accomplish this but you will need Realm Object Server on the backend and the reachability triggers as other's have mentioned.